# React: render list Object directly from function inside <ul></ul> with an id?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a HTML document with an input field and a button that takes the value from the input field when clicked and renders a new `<li>` object inside an `<ul>` object on my HTML page.

What I basically want, is to create a `<list>` element with the value of the input field when clicking the "add" button. And then inserting that list object inside my `<ul id="list"></ul>` object with the id of "list". Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Greeter</title>
    <script src="libs/react.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="libs/browser.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="reactHere"></div>

  </body>

  <script type ="text/babel">
    class MyComponent extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state= {
        listEntry: ''
        }
      };

      onInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({
            listEntry: event.target.value
          });
      };

      addListObject() {
        ReactDOM.render(<li>{this.state.ListEntry}</li>, document.getElementById('liste'));
      };

      render() {
        return (
        <div>
          <h1>Hello World!</h1>
          <label for="inputName">Eingabe Listeneintrag:</label>
          <input 
          name="inputName"
          value={this.state.listEntry}
          onChange={(e)=>this.onInputChange(e)}>        
          </input>
          <button 
          onclick = {(e)=>this.addListObject}
          >
          Add
          </button>
          <ul id="liste"></ul>
        </div>
        );
      }

    }  


    ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('reactHere'));
  </script>
</html>
```

I am still very new to React, so my first question is, is there a way to render the list element directly from a function (e.g when clicking a button) and place it e.g inside a `<ul>` object specifying some "id"?
Or do I have to first create an external extra Component class and render that List object inside ReactDOM.render() function again?

Because I find this very minimalistic and inconvenient to create a wrapper class for every bits of html code that has some function, and then call the ReactDOM.render() function whenever I want to do or change my html dynamically... is this how React works or am I thinking too hard?

I know that in above code, I am calling the ReactDOM.render() function to create my new list object but thats obviously wrong... 
But if it's somehow possible to create it in a function on the fly... it would make things easier..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React - Dynamic creation of List item inside component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46514351/react-dynamic-creation-of-list-item-inside-component)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing this is what you're essentially trying to achieve?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.24.0/babel.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="reactHere"></div>


<script type="text/babel">
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { list: [], value: '' };
    this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
    this.addListObject = this.addListObject.bind(this);
  }
   
  addListObject () {
    const state = this.state;
    state.list.push(this.state.value);
    state.value = '';
    this.setState(state);
  }

  onInputChange (event) {
    const state = this.state;
    state.value = event.target.value;
    this.setState(state);
  }
  
  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
        <h1> Hello World! </h1> 
        <label for="inputName"> Eingabe Listeneintrag: < /label> 
        <input id="inputName" value={this.state.value} onChange={this.onInputChange}/>
        <button onClick={this.addListObject}>Add</button> 
        <ul>{this.state.list.map((li, i) => <li key={i}>{li}</li>)}</ul> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < MyComponent / > , document.getElementById('reactHere'));
</script>
```

Comment: yup thanks, works like that but I find that React code where you can mix javascript /JSX with html code quite a bit messy to overlook.. And also if you have to create many components as a kind of wrapper around html... its easy to loose track of what component is doing what, or not?

Comment: hey, another question: can I somehow avoid that binding of my methods to my class object in the constructor of my class? e.g if I use  ES6 arrow functions inside my render() function for my html elements, is that a safe thing to do?

Comment: I think your first statement, that depends on the context, if you've structured your project well, then it should be relatively easy to find what component does what, I mean if you're using webpack and all that jazzy stuff, then it should be pretty clean. You can always use ```this.x.bind``` when you wish to handle some event, I did it in the constructor because you may want to call that method multiple times. Finally, as for having arrow functions inside the render method, yest that's safe to do, only time it isn't is when you use ```dangerouslySetInnerHTML```.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so you need to learn the few things first,

1. In react `onclick` should be written as `onClick` its a casesensitive
2. You should not append the li directly to the ui elements its a bad practice you need to use the state and update the dom.
3. Your state design is bad you need 2 things here, 1st is listobject which will be for the textbox and 2nd for the list of the listobject entered by the user.

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          listEntry: '',
          list: []
        }
        this.onInputChange = this.onInputChange.bind(this);
        this.addListObject = this.addListObject.bind(this);
      };
```

note here the state change I have added list to state

```
  addListObject() {
    this.setState({
      list: this.state.list.concat(this.state.listEntry),
      listEntry: ''
    });
  };
```

here, I am adding the current entry to the list and clearing the list entry.

```
<ul id="liste">{
          this.state.list.map(a => {
            return <li key={a}>{a}</li>
          })
        }</ul>
```

here, I am looping over the lists and binding them, check the key I added to li to tell the react to not to update every time. learn more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html).

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-idktz8)

Comment: thanks, wasn't aware anymore how to create new elements by simply javascript or JSX expression...I somehow have to get used to that state and event thing in React... somehow wholly new concept to me ;). Nice trick to reset the state of listEntry every time the button is clicked... I thought it would get messy with the whole state thing at some point in time.. you have to basically keep track of every thing the user could do in your component class, right?

Comment: @user2883596 mostly state would do the all things for you, its like database for you, if you still want to give some dynamic contents to the dom you can refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30721981/2630817 I still advice you to stick up to one root element and use the state to rest elements.

Answer (score 0):

Does this makes sense to you?

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state= {
       listEntry: '',
       entries: []
    }
  };

  onInputChange(event) {
    this.setState({
        listEntry: event.target.value
      });
  };

  addListObject() {
    this.setState({
      entries: this.state.entries.concat({name: this.state.listEntry})
    })
  };

  renderEntries = () => {
     this.state.entries.map((entry, i) => return <li key={i}>{entry.name}</li>)
  } 

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
      <label for="inputName">Eingabe Listeneintrag:</label>
      <input 
      name="inputName"
      value={this.state.listEntry}
      onChange={(e)=>this.onInputChange(e)}>        
      </input>
      <button 
      onclick = {() => this.addListObject()}
      >
      Add
      </button>
      <ul id="liste">{this.renderEntries()}</ul>
    </div>
    );
  }

}  


ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('reactHere'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store an array to hold the list in your state then use the array to render list item inside the **ul**. Check the code snippet below here

https://codesandbox.io/s/zn5jmm8jwl